# DDD - Restricting repository to create only certain entity

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have one important question about repository and entity. Should I restrict repository to create specific entity/aggregate root (via generic repositories like BaseRepository)?

At this moment, base repository have access to database factory object (not DbFactory but custom) to retrieve any POCO (not just related to aggregate root). So, technically, I can create any entity from any repository. Obviously, as a programmer I don't do it but it's definitely possible. So, is it necessary to restrict repository and allow it to create specific entity? Note that some entities have sub entities as well. So, if I restrict repository to create one entity (via BaseRepository) then how to create sub entities?

Comment: Do you mean "create" as in introduce a new entity/aggregate root in the system or rehydrate a previously stored entity ? The *"database factory object to retrieve any POCO"* part makes it quite unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider it clear to have a Repository for each aggregate root in your Bounded Context.

It will make it obvious what an aggregate root is in your application opposed to what are (sub) entities. This way you are protecting yourself and others from harming how aggregates are accessed and used through repositories.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jonas suggests in his answer, I'd create *one repository per aggregate root*.  These should hide all persistence detail.  This means taking domain entities as parameters and returning domain entities.  Usually mapping from ORM entity to domain entity within the repository.  As a side-effect, this also makes you think about what data you need, reducing some of the horrors you can encounter in DDD dealing with entities that have lazy-loaded properties.

I'd avoid the generic repository pattern, like you say in your original post, in DDD you want your code to *document your design intention*, you don't want to provide code that allows clients/callers to load any entity from your database.  Also, most of your entities will most likely be built from **many** tables/resources, which doesn't apply well to the generic repository pattern.

Comment: I agree with you. Actually, I already got the answer from http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern